# Parse - Query and send push notification to custom class

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to send a push notification to users when the data in the submission class that I created changes in the status column but keep getting an error in XCode in the "let pushQuery = PFsubmission.query()" that I have "use of unresolved identifier 'PFsubmission'."

```
        //install push function
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.addUniqueObject("Status", forKey: "channels")
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    let pushQuery = PFsubmission.query()
    pushQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: "1")

    // Send push notification to query
    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery) // Set our Installation query
    push.setMessage("Test One Message Here")
    push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not using this framework, but I cannot help noticing that the Parse framework class names follow this schema:

```
PFClass  // not PFclass
```

i.e. with a capitalized class name after `PF`. You should try using

```
PFSubmission // not PFsubmission
```

and see if that works.